# Changing barchart dynamically using dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts, bar-chart

I'm using barchart to my project, I'd like to change the data dynamically by data from database.

**So here is my barchart code in js:**

```
Highcharts.chart('wilayah', {
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: kode_bantuan
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Barchart by Wilayah'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: kanwil,
            crosshair: true
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Rupiah? (Rp)'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} </b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'clean',
            data: cleanwil

        }, {
            name: 'Salcred',
            data: salcredwil

        }, {
            name: 'Penyerapan',
            data: penyerapanwil

        }, {
            name: 'persn',
            data: []

        }]
    });
```

So basically this code show my barchart, I'm going to change the data dynamically using dropdown to trigger it.

So I insert some code when the dropdown triggered:

```
    wilayah.data.datasets.push({
          title: 'testing',
          backgroundColor: '#ff0000',
          data: [1,2,3]
        });
        wilayah.update();
```

Is it wrong to do it those way? 
here maybe my code in fidle https://jsfiddle.net/k6mgqr59/

Comment: Is it working properly?

Comment: I think you need to call `AJAX` call `onChange` event of dropdown and then fetch your `JSON` according to High Chart and simply put that output in to it so that it works accordingly.

Comment: @HarishSoni yup it works properly, but the update code not work. still dont get how to do it

Comment: @H45H yup already did that, sorry i dont write my code completely but in my code already put it on onchange

Comment: your `data` property is an array and you are pushing the value in the Array directly this isn't allowed.

Try `wilayah.data[0].datasets.push({` Instead

Comment: @HarishSoni still wont work, dont know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close to the solution, however, (based on your jsfiddle example) you've made a simple mistake.

```
function updatedata() {
  wilayah.series[0].setData([5, 5, 5]);
  wilayah.update();
}
```

Here you've `wilayah` variable, which is not the chart reference. The solution is to make this reference like that:

```
var wilayah = Highcharts.chart('wilayah', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  title: {
    text: kode_bantuan_wil
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'Barchart by Wilayah'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: kanwil,
    crosshair: true
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Rupiah? (Rp)'
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
    pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
      '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} </b></td></tr>',
    footerFormat: '</table>',
    shared: true,
    useHTML: true
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      pointPadding: 0.2,
      borderWidth: 0
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'clean',
    data: cleanwil

  }, {
    name: 'Salcred',
    data: salcredwil

  }, {
    name: 'Penyerapan',
    data: penyerapanwil

  }, {
    name: 'persn',
    data: []

  }]
});
```

**Demo:** 
https://jsfiddle.net/8sxm2p9r/

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good example on how to add date to data sets
[Highcharts Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/dynamic-update/)

```
            var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
            series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
```